# Sequelize findOrCreate method throws "no where parameter" message

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

When executing the code below to address my AWS-managed PostgreSQL (assuming Entity is a well defined model that I've already saved the given primary key "Entity" to)

```
      Entity.findOrCreate({where: {entity: 'Salad'}, defaults: {type: 'Food'}})
      .spread(function(user, created) {
        console.log(user.get({
          plain: true
        }));
        console.log(created);
      });
```

I am returned the error

```
Error: Missing where attribute in the options parameter passed to findOrCreate. Please note 
that the API has changed, and is now options only (an object with where, defaults keys, 
transaction etc.)
```

The code above is pulled directly from their documentation though. Is this bad error handling signaling another issue or should I file a ticket with the Sequelize team?

Comment: have u tried running it without the `defaults` option? i.e. `Entity.findOrCreate({where: {entity: 'Salad'}}`. And I understand `entity` is a field in your `Entity` object?

Comment: @kennasoft Yes, I have tried running without the defaults and it throws the same error. Yes, entity is a field in the Entity model.